# How to pick up column by given parameters and then sum-up the column total in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I've got a table like below. I would like to pickup the column first by given parameters then sum up the total of the column.

For example, by given Parameter of **SGD**, I would like to sum-up the total amount of column SGD.

```
Date     SO NO. AUD         SGD             HKD
7/1/2019    SO1 100      105.17          545.74 
8/5/2019    SO2 130      122.01          691.13 
9/9/2019    SO3 160      150.32          853.55 
9/15/2019   SO4 180      169.11          960.25
```

Thanks

Comment: provide more info. What parameters? the answer to this question seems like creating a measure `=SUM(SGD)`

Comment: Hi Martin, as now I would like to calculate the total sum of AUD/SGD/HKD based on a power bi slicer of these three currency. For example, it picks up sum(AUD) when I selected "AUD" in the currency slicer and it picks up sum(SGD) when I selected "SGD" in the currency slicer.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to add a new disconnected table `Currencies` with one column `Currency` and values `AUD`, `SGD` and `HKD`. Add a slicer for it and make it drop down.

Then create a measure, which will take the value of the slicer and calculate total on the corresponding column, depending on the selection in the slider:

```
Total = SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE('Currencies'[Currency]; "AUD");
    "AUD"; SUMX('Table'; [AUD]);
    "SGD"; SUMX('Table'; [SGD]);
    "HKD"; SUMX('Table'; [HKD]);
    SUMX('Table'; [AUD]))
```

`SELECTEDVALUE('Currencies'[Currency]; "AUD")` will return the value selected in the slicer, or `AUD` if none or multiple values are selected. See [SELECTEDVALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectedvalue-function).

[`SWITCH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/switch-function-dax) will compare this value with a list of possible options (`AUD`, `SGD` and `HKD`) and return corresponding expression (`SUMX('Table'; [AUD])`, `SUMX('Table'; [SGD])` or `SUMX('Table'; [HKD])`), or some default value if there is no match (`SUMX('Table'; [AUD])`).

Then use this measure in your report, and it's value will change depending on the selection in the slicer:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andrey, worked exactly what I expected. Just one thing, the ";" should be "," in all above code. Thanks again.

Comment: The separator could be either semicolon or comma, depending on the regional settings of your computer.