# How to create a filter for numerical values column in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I've a data model set up where column cost value is in HKD and another new measure is created to get cost value in USD by converting HKD values to USD conversion rate, now when I am visualising is there a way I can create a  filter so that I can show values by switching between HKD and USD?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58369013/how-to-pick-up-column-by-given-parameters-and-then-sum-up-the-column-total-in-po

Comment: I created the same as mentioned after creating disconnected table, here is my logic                                                                                                                   Currency =SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE('Currency'[Currency];"AUD");"AUD";SUMX(Table;[Value.AUD]);"USD";Sumx(Table;[Value.USD]);Sumx(Table;[Value.AUD]))    However I don't see any values populating in currency column and in my table Value AUD is new measure i.e Value.AUD = Value.USD*1.2434